# Android Studio Gradle/RecyclerView

Tags: android

Pls help me to solve it....Im using android studio 2.3.3 and trying to Add RecyclerView

And Below these i have red line =/

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'

compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1'
```

Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.

> Manifest merger failed : Attribute meta-data#android.support.VERSION@value value=(25.3.1) from [com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1] AndroidManifest.xml:27:9-31
>       is also present at [com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:26.0.0-alpha1] AndroidManifest.xml:24:9-38 value=(26.0.0-alpha1).
>       Suggestion: add 'tools:replace="android:value"' to  element at AndroidManifest.xml:25:5-27:34 to override.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using different versions of Support Libraries. Make sure to always use the same versions across support libraries, e.g.:

```
compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:25.3.1'
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
```